# Floating point layouting and rounding

Tags: python, layout, rendering

I have a node in a render-tree that calculates its height based on it's children. Position and size values are allowed to be floating-point values, rounding is done at render-time.

```
    def compute_size(self):
        # Invokes compute_size() of child nodes.
        super(InlineBoxNode, self).compute_size()

        # Iterate over all children and compute the current nodes
        # height.
        self.h = 0
        for node in self.children:
            self.h += node.h
```

The problem I'm facing is the following: Imagine two nodes being child of the node of the code above. Both children have a height of `10.5`. The child-nodes are layed out below their respective previous node, i.e. node two will be placed at `y=10.5`. At render-time `10.5` becomes `11`. The second node now is at `y=11` and has `h=11`, i.e. it's bottom edge is at `22`, not `21`. (See the image below for demonstration)

**I think this issue could be solved by always rounding floored (i.e. to the lower neighboring integer value), but would the semantics be correct?**

[image]

---

### Edit

I just realized that even rounding floored only does not solve it. The bottom-edge of the second node is now at `20`, but `21` would be correct.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the internal representation is float and the actual layout is in pixels. There must be some sort of rounding involved. Then do the same rounding operation before addition, e.g.

```
self.h += int(node.h)
```

in your case.